# configuring Oracle AppBundler to include part of jre/bin/ in PlugIns folder of app

Tags: java, oracle

In the documentation for Oracle AppBundler (https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html), it says "By default, only the contents of the `jre/` directory will be included with the bundled application. All executable content (i.e. `bin/`, `jre/bin/`) is excluded. Additional content can be included or excluded using nested `<include>` and `<exclude>` elements, respectively."

I would like to include part of `jre/bin/` in the bundle, but I've been unable to figure out the precise syntax for requesting this. In particular, this doesn't have any effect:

```
<runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}">
  <include name="jre/bin"/>
</runtime>
```

(I.e., the above yields the same result as not using the `<include>` at all.)